# How to create a function whose parameters can be used in a nested loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

Beginner here,

I have to create a long array of numbers using a function with 3 parameters that work the same way as loop (start, end, step)

I have tried creating my function with parameters (x, y, z) and integrate a nested loop inside that reuse those parameters but i'm stuck.

```js
let range = function(x, y, z) {
  let array = []
  for (let i = x; i < y; z++) {
    array.push()
  } 
  return range[i]
}

console.log(range(0, 10, 2))
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to write `for (let i = x; i < y; i += z)`. But there are other things that makes no sense on the code, like returning `range[i]`, or `arr.push()` without declaration of `arr` variable.

Comment: So, lots of problems here.  First off, `i` is never being adjusted, so i will always be less than `y`, resulting in an infinite loop.  `arr.push()` isn't pushing anything to it, and `arr` is undefined.  Shouldn't it be `array`?  And then you're returning `range[i]`.  Shouldn't that be returning `array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. There were some issues though;

The worst is that you are running into an infinite loop by not incrementing the counter (so the condition `i < y` is always `true`)

Then I'm not sure what you wanted to do with the array !? 

(I don't think is needed unless you want to do some other logic)

Anyways here is a working example on how to make a loop use the params for:

- initialization
- final condition
- step

```js
function range(x, y, z) {
  const numbers = [];
  
  for (let i = x; i < y; i += z) {
    numbers.push(i);
  } 
  
  return numbers;
}

console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
```

Comment: i have to return the result of the function and put it inside of the array

Comment: @OlivierCarignan result of what? What exactly should this loop calculate ?

Comment: it is supposed to calculate a series of numbers let's say from 0 (x) to 100 (y) according to an increment (z)